Can I use nouns/adjectives with ...てもいいです(か)?
By 「...てもいいです(か)」 I mean the pattern for giving or asking permission.
I know nouns & adjectives are OK with the negative variant, ...なくてもいいです, for example 医者じゃなくてもいいです = "It's OK if I he's not a doctor", プレゼントが高くなくてもいいです = "The gift doesn't have to be expensive."
But how about with affirmative ...てもいいです(か)? Every example I can find only uses verbs, so I'm not sure. Are the examples below OK?
無職でもいいです(か)。 It's (Is it) OK if I'm unemployed
プレゼントが安くてもいいです(か)。It's (Is it) OK if the gift is cheap
音が大きくてもいいです(か)。 It's (Is it) OK if the sound is loud

Yes, your three examples are perfectly valid sentences. But it would be worth noting that they might sound slightly immature or unsophisticated. Mature adults tend to prefer 無職でも構いません or 無職でも大丈夫です over 無職でもいいです in polite conversation (here's why).
